# How to reattach detached cable onto a drain hand auger?

Tags: repair, tools, drain, drainage, hand-tools

I have this drain hand [auger](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-4-in-x-25-ft-Power-Pistol-Grip-Drum-Auger-BC86250/202755049), But the cable is detached when I extend it out for cleaning, now I don't know how to attach and wind it back onto the device, I also can't find any manual or tutorial that teaches it.

Answer (score 0):

On the small drum auggers I have there is a small clamp inside that holds the cable in place. I did have 1 very cheap unit that the cable was not attached to anything it used the coil inside the drum to hold it in place the problem with this model was when you get close to the end the cable can spin and this can make it tough if already through a couple of bends.

Answer (score -2):

Throw that cheap thing away and get a good one:

[image]